# web3.py equivalent to geth console command eth.pendingTransactions

Tags: go-ethereum, web3.py

I'm currently running a geth server and use the geth console for sysadmin stuff, while using `web3.py` for interfacing with geth programmatically. From the geth console, there is a handy command `eth.pendingTransactions` that shows all the pending transactions local to my geth server.

A Google search for a similar `web3.py` command yields some info on Github regarding [web3.txpool](https://github.com/cogeorg/teaching/wiki/Web3-Python-API#tx-pool)

Unfortunately, this shows all pending PUBLIC transactions that will be included in the next mainnet block. What I want to see, however, are transactions that are only local to my geth node.

For this use case do I have to code something up myself, or is there a good method I can use?

Answer (score 0):

Filtering the pending transactions for the sending account of interest is the way to go.